# Google Firebase authentication in ReactNative App

Tags: javascript, react-native, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I was developing an app which I like implements Firebase as Authenticating system.

My problem comes when I try to set up the Authentication with Google provider when I try to modify the colletion of firestore where the users are saved. My code is the following:

```
export const loginWithGoogle = () => {
  const navigation = useNavigation();
  useEffect(() => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      navigation.navigate('/RegisterScreen');
    }, 10000);
  }, []);

  return () => {
    return firebase
      .auth()
      .signInWithPopup(Providers.google)
      .then(async result => {
        //console.log(result.credential.accessToken);
        const user = result.user;
        console.log(user);

        //This 2 lines below doesn't work to get the colletion.
        db.('users').setItem('userid', user!.uid);
        collection.(db,'users').setItem('photoURL', user!.photoURL);

        //TODO if userid exists IN USERS db then use update IF NULL use set
        await db.collection('users').doc(user!.uid).update({
          // id: user.uid,
          name: user!.displayName,
          email: user!.email,
          phone: user!.phoneNumber,
          photoURL: user!.photoURL,
        });
      })
      .then(() => {
        navigation.navigate('ProtectedScreen');
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
};
```

So I guess that my error comes from unknowledge of how to manage data saved on firestore.

If you can help take thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are some thing we need to clear here:

You can just merge the data. There is no need to read/get it from `Firestore` to check if it is there and save it onyl if it's not. You will be charged for `reads` and `writes`. In the end it's cheaper to always just write without checking if something exists.

Also this code here:

```
db.('users').setItem('userid', user!.uid);
collection.(db,'users').setItem('photoURL', user!.photoURL);
```

especially with the `db.(` and `collection.(` doens't look good. Even if it is it's not for getting data but for saving it.

Could you pls clarify witch Firebase SDK you use: version 8 or 9. Also pls check a little bit the docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data).

Comment: The main reason of check iif the data exists is check if there some uid of the user, to manage on a diferent way if that the case. But my main question was, what do you really do on the method sighInWithGoogle??

Comment: I would also recommend to use the `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged` to get the user data. That way you don't need to handle the `sighInWithGoogle`. As soon the user is signed in (it doesn't matter what provider) you would get his data and then you can do what ever you want with it.

Comment: Okey, so that is a most funcional way, in order you don't care about the kind of authentication. I get I try !

Comment: Check this answer to. It's a little more detailed: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69034201/5519300